# How to copy files from server to docker container

Tags: docker, containers, docker-for-windows

I am trying to create a Windows Nano Server container and copy some files from server to the new container. Below is my dockerfile code:

```
FROM microsoft/nanoserver
MAINTAINER test@gmail.com
COPY C:/files/ C:/files/
```

When I run it, I am getting below error:

> Copy failed:createFile
>   \?\c:\programdata\Docker\tmp\docker-builder78565487\files: The system
>   canot find the path specified.

How do I declare source location in `COPY` command, so it uses absolute path and copy files to **c:\files location** on my container.

Comment: I think your slashes are wrong way COPY ["*.ps1", "c:\\startup\\"]

Comment: Unfortunately same error

Comment: You source directory shall be under the same root where your dockerfile is, you can not reference stuff outside of root directory

Comment: See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy for limitation what your source directory can be

Comment: Thanks Gregory,moving files to root dir fixed the issue.

Comment: I will provide answer below, accept it as solution

Comment: I found that same situation in a VS2017 Solution when the build is started by docker compose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not copy files outside of context of the build. Move files which needs to be copied in the same folder where `dockerfile` is.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy