# How to copy files from other location into Docker image

Tags: java, maven, docker

I am trying to copy files from other location (in windows from D drive that is shared drive also) to my image.
But it is giving me error.

> Step 5/8 : ADD ${APP_PATH}/${ARTIFACT}-${VERSION} /opt/tomcat/webapps/${ARTIFACT}-${VERSION}
>   ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder990684261/d:/Application_Build/spring-tournament-portal-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: no such file or directory

**Scenario:**

I am trying to make test,build,release phase cycle with the help of docker.
So My Multistage docker file's first version looked like this

```
FROM maven as build
WORKDIR /usr/local
RUN mkdir app
COPY . /usr/local/app/spring-tournament-portal/
WORKDIR /usr/local/app/spring-tournament-portal
RUN mvn -e package

FROM tomcat
ENV PORT 8080
ENV VERSION 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
ENV ARTIFACT spring-tournament-portal
ENV JPDA_ADDRESS 8000
ENV JPDA_TRANSPORT dt_socket
COPY --from=build /usr/local/app/${ARTIFACT}/target/${ARTIFACT}-${VERSION}  /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/${ARTIFACT}-${VERSION}
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat/bin
CMD ["catalina.sh jpda run"]
EXPOSE ${PORT}
```

But on every build maven fetches its dependency. So it was taking too much time.
So i made another approach. I created two docker files(One for build and other for release).

**Over here the role of build docker file does is copy all source code into an image only. So that when i will create container, I could easily create volume for maven dependency to avoid redownloading:-**

```
FROM indiver/tournament-base
RUN apt-get update && \
        apt-get install -y \
        -o APT::Install-Recommend=false -o APT::Install-Suggests=false \
        maven

WORKDIR /usr/local
COPY . /spring-tournament-portal/
WORKDIR /spring-tournament-portal
COPY ./docker/dev/entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Here is entrypoint.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$@" Phase is executing.....
mvn  clean "$@"
```

When i run the image after building docker file with the help of docker-compose.xml. I set volume for dependency folder.

**Here is docker compose.xml**

```
version: "2"

services:
 test-service:
  build:
   context: ../../
   dockerfile: ./docker/dev/Dockerfile
  container_name: "test-service" 
  command: 'test'
  volumes:
   - .m2:/root/.m2
 build-service:
  build:
   context: ../../
   dockerfile: ./docker/dev/Dockerfile
  container_name: "build-service" 
  command: 'package'
  env_file:
    - ./EnvironmentConstant.env
  volumes:
   - .m2:/root/.m2
 database-service:
  container_name: "database-service" 
  env_file:
    - ./EnvironmentConstant.env
  image: mysql
  ports: 
   - "3306:3306"
  volumes:  
   - ./dev-mysql:/var/lib/mysql
  networks:
   -  app-network

networks:
 app-network:
  driver: bridge
```

So it does not need to redownload the dependency again that is in **.m2** volume.

After that i need to create release image having content of build prepared by maven. But container of build service is already stopped. So i need to use **docker cp** command to get my prepared build.

```
docker cp build-service:/spring-tournament-portal/target/spring-tournament-portal-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT D:/Application_Build
```

Now i want build that is in Application_Build folder should be copied into my release image.
So my release docker file looks like

```
FROM indiver/tournament-release

ENV APP_PATH=d:/Application_Build
ENV ARTIFACT=spring-tournament-portal
ENV VERSION=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
ADD ${APP_PATH}/${ARTIFACT}-${VERSION} /opt/tomcat/webapps/${ARTIFACT}-${VERSION}
WORKDIR /opt/tomcat/bin
ENTRYPOINT ["catalina.sh", "jpda", "run"]
EXPOSE ${PORT}
```

But As i have mentioned above it is giving me error

```
Step 5/8 : ADD ${APP_PATH}/${ARTIFACT}-${VERSION} /opt/tomcat/webapps/${ARTIFACT}-${VERSION} ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder990684261/d:/Application_Build/spring-tournament-portal-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: no such file or directory.
```

I tried to copy by COPY and ADD command. But nothing is working. How can i achieve this.

If It can be achieved this with the help of other relatively easy flow. It would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

The Dockerfile reference says:

> ADD obeys the following rules:
>
> The path must be inside the context of the build.
>   ...

Comment: Similar question was answered on SO, please check. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48392029/how-to-copy-files-from-server-to-docker-container

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  I was trying to copy from ~/.m2 on my local machine and it wouldn't let me.   This answer resolved the issue for me.   I just temporarily put the .m2 artifacts i wanted cached into my local docker build folder.

Answer (score 1):

Overall your approach seems to be too complicated to me and a very non micro-services way of doing things.

I would suggest that you copy your dependencies into the binary that you are creating to create a self contained fat (uber) jar, which you can copy to the docker image, the way spring boot does.

You approach for having separate docker files for different environments is also problematic and could result in unexpected conditions in production.

Answer (score 1):

So I too faced this similar problem . 
You can try the below listed command and replace the Square brackets with your path:

"**docker cp /[Your Source Directory] [ContainerId]:/[Destination Path]**"